# IPAM installation fails due to insufficient SQL permissions

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipam

### Goal

I'm trying to install IP Address Management (IPAM) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server, against a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 database engine instance, instead of using the Microsoft Windows Internal Database (WID).

### Configuration

- VMware Workstation 10
- Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition with Service Pack 1 (installed locally)

### Problem

When I try to install IPAM through **Server Manager**, I get the message below.

> IPAM Deployment failed with the following error.
>
> Failed to create database schema.
>
> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>
> You can restart this provisioning wizard from the IPAM overview page.

[image: IPAM Installation Failure]

### Question

Does anyone know what **SQL Server** permissions are required to install IPAM using the IPAM server's credentials?

Comment: Um, have you tried granting `CREATE DATABASE` permissions?  Something makes me think you might need those.

Comment: I granted the computer's Active Directory computer account the `sysadmin` role on the database engine instance. That includes the `CREATE DATABASE` permission, among most others.

Comment: Doesn't look like the `MASTER` DB agrees with that.  So, check the permissions on `MASTER` explicitly - I'll bet they didn't propagate down.  IIRC, your account just needs the `DB Creator` role in `MASTER`, but if that doesn't work, try admin rights.